# Mathematical frak  with subscript 'x' in ggplot2 label

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts, webfonts, font-style

I want to have  with subscript 'x' (normal R font). It doesn't need to be using the font_add_google function, any solution is appreciated. Thanks!
The unicode is U1D505 if this might be helpful.

```
font_add_google(name = 'UnifrakturMaguntia','fraktur')
showtext_auto()
df <- data.frame()
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_point() + 
  xlim(0, 10) + 
  ylim(0, 100) + 
  ylab(bquote(B[x])) + 
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = "fraktur", size = 20),
        title = element_text(family="sans"))
showtext_auto(FALSE)
```

I tried what I wrote above.

Comment: Have you tried `ylab(bquote("\U1D505"[x]))`?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work. Just plots an empty box.

Comment: Hm. Probably one of these annoying font or device issues. On my Mac I get empty boxes too when I use the default graphics device. But it works fine when I use `Cairo` or r`AGG`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLpky.png.